# Spring : create object with id from another table

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created objects User and Message, and now I want, that message's id will be associated with the user id. How can I do it with annotations or with something else?
[Table User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHvx3.png)
[Table Messge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5ApT.png)

Message class

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class  , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Comment: Do you want that just a single message is associated with a user?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can try this:

Message class:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userId;

}
```

user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class  , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonBackReference
    private set<Message> messages;
}
```